# Photos App showing blank photos after doing Recover All

Tags: iphone, ios

Last week I had to backup my iPhone X due to it reaching it’s storage limit (64gb). My plan was to use iTunes to do a backup and then delete the photos in my photos app. I was able to successfully backup and delete the photos no problem.

After a few days, the MacBook I used to backup my photos broke. The Apple service center people told me that to repair the MacBook they had to replace the logic board and reformat it’s disk drive. I had no choice but to let them do their thing and format the drive and replace the board.

Since the MacBook broke, I panicked and tried to recover the photos in my iPhone. Luckily the photos are still in the recently deleted folder. I tried to do a Recover all, but not all photos came  back. There are some photos that are blank an example of what I’m talking about can be seen in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qP7Uo.jpg

If anybody can point me in the right direction on how to recover these blank photos, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  How long have you been waiting for the photos to recover?  Are they backed-up to iCloud, too?

Comment: It's been more than 3 weeks now and the pictures are still shown like the one in the linked image. Sadly, the photos aren't backed up to iCloud